# expand parent to same height as child (position: absolute) without javascript

Tags: css

How to expand the parent to have the same height as the child (the content) when the child has `position: absolute` ?

- The height of the child **is not** static
- Solution without javascript

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    test<br>test<br>test<br>test
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  some text below parent
</div>
```

([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gusz9r3d/3/))

Comment: Do you need your child to be `position:absolute` or you just want it to be on the right side ? Because I don't think you can set the parent size depending on a absolutely positioned child

Comment: The child must be absolute

Answer (score -1):

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    width: max-content;
}
```

on the parent

Comment: Can you provide an example? Doesn't work for me

Comment: I've updated the answer. Note, it will work only when the `.child` has a defined width property